# Cannot run webproject on .net core docker

Tags: debian, docker, port-forwarding, .net

I have installed the official .net core docker container from Microsoft with the followed commands on my debian machine:

```
docker pull microsoft/dotnet:latest
```

and

```
docker run -it microsoft/dotnet:latest
```

Then I wanted to make a new test website

```
mkdir test

cd test

dotnet new -t web

dotnet restore

dotnet run
```

Then I committed the changes:

```
docker commit 0240ad83aae4 dotnet_core
```

And made a port forwarding, so I could access the website from outside the docker container.

```
docker run -itp 8080:5000 dotnet_core:latest /bin/bash
```

But when I try to access the website over port 8080 nothing happened.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: When I try to access localhost over port 5000 in the .net core docker container over curl it works. But when I try to connect from outside the docker container over port 8080 it does not work, although I made portforwarding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution I added the line

```
.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000")
```

to the main method

in the "Program.cs" file

Now it works.

https://github.com/aspnet/Templates/issues/394